# Dynamic Sql use of variables within subselect

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to use variables within my update statement but for some reason I don't understand it gives an error.

The following code works:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql='update valuetable set waarde=(select top 1 firstname from DimEmployee where firstname not like ''%[0-9]%'' )'
exec (@sql)
```

If I change firstname and DimEmployee to variables using the following code:

```
declare @column nvarchar(max);
declare @table nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @column='firstname';
set @table='dbo.dimEmployee'
set @sql='update valuetable set waarde=(select top 1 '+ @column + 'from '+@table+' where '+@column+' not like ''%[0-9]%'')'
exec (@sql)
```

it gives the following error: Incorrect syntax near '.' on line 1

Could somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong and if there's a fix for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should print out the SQL to see what you are actually running.  For instance, it is obvious that the lack of space before `from` is an issue:

```
set @sql = '
update valuetable
    set waarde = (select top 1 '+ @column + ' from ' + @table + ' where ' + @column + ' not like ''%[0-9]%'')
';
```